# COSMOS DB Joins TOP operator

Tags: linq, multidimensional-array, azure-cosmosdb

In cosmos db can I take top 1 from all the documents and get all inner array?

For example, i have 50 documents of this format i want tags array section from latest inserted document

```
  { "id": "19015",   "description": "Snacks, granola bars, hard, plain",   "tags": [
    {
      "name": "snacks"
    },
    {
      "name": "granola bars"
    },
    {
      "name": "hard"
    },
    {
      "name": "plain"
    }   ],   "foodGroup": "Snacks",   "informationDate": "dates"

}
```

I am doing  `select top 1 f.name from c join f in c.tags` but i am getting only this as result `{ "name" : "snacks"}` of latest document. is there any way i can get all the array in the latest document?

My expected result is

```
{
          "name": "snacks"
        },
        {
          "name": "granola bars"
        },
        {
          "name": "hard"
        },
        {
          "name": "plain"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this query?

```
SELECT TOP 1 VALUE c.tags FROM c ORDER BY c._ts DESC
```

It returns below.

```
[
    {
        "name": "snacks"
    },
    {
        "name": "granola bars"
    },
    {
        "name": "hard"
    },
    {
        "name": "plain"
    }
]
```